# Rails app confused about environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration

I created a new Ruby on Rails app (first app I'm working on in Rails 3), and for some reason, my app seems to be confused about what environment it should be running in (unless I'm just confused).

When I run `rake db:create`, it's creating both the "myapp_development" and "myapp_test" databases.  When I subsequently run `rake db:drop`, it drops the development database, but not the test database.

What's going on?

**Edit 1:** Here's what my database.yml file looks like:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_development
  username: root
  password: 

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_test
  username: root
  password: 

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_production
  username: root
  password:
```

**Edit 2:** Tried recreating a new app from scratch, and still have the same issue.  Here's what I did.

1. Created a new rails app:

```
rails new myapp
```

2. Edited my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'mysql', '2.8.1'

# Bundle the extra gems:
gem 'warden', '1.0.3'
gem 'devise', '1.2.1'
gem 'geokit'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug'
end
```

3. Edited my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_development
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_test
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: myapp_production
  username: root
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

4. Running `rake db:create` at this point creates both `myapp_development` and `myapp_test`.  If I proceed to run `rake db:drop` followed by `rake db:create`, I get a command line warning stating "myapp_test already exists" since the drop only removes `myapp_development`, but the create attempts to create both dev and test databases.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. I'm running rake db:create and rails creates both development and test schemas. When I run rake db:drop it drops only the development schema.

It's certainly an environment configuration issue since it works properly in one machine (a macos snow leopard) but doesn't on my new machine (a macos lion). I'm still trying to figure out the differences between the envs of the two machines that might be causing this behavior. Any tip is appreciated. Will post if I find something.

Comment: I never found a resolution to this, so I'd be happy to hear if you figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

It would only create the development and test databases if you ran `rake db:create:all`, not `rake db:create`. The latter will only create one or the other, depending on the environment you're working in.

Comment: Right, but I'm not running `rake db:create:all`, I'm just running `rake db:create`, and it's creating both the test and development databases.  I've added my databases.yml file to my question in case this helps.

Answer (score 0):

check your 
`config/database.yml` 
file in your app for the database configuration, you probably want test around though. but database.yml will let you access everything. It will use the development db by default though then you specify when to use production

Also a note, just running `rake db:migrate` will create the databases if they don't exist and migrate your models, you might want to use that instead

Comment: I added the contents of my database.yml file to the question.